# How to create a searching alghoritm for the text file in C

Tags: c, search, text

I need to create a searching algorithm that will loop through the file, find a specific line based on input, and store it in the array.

```
o - after activation, the program will load the measurement module (in the format of a capital character and two
numbers), the type of the measurement quantity and lists the values sorted by time and date
measurement date and time. This command will return the list even if the 'n' command has not been activated (i.e.
dynamic fields for individual items from the input file have not yet been created).
If the file is not open (i.e. the 'v' command has not yet been executed), this option does not change anything
and prints the message Not opened file.
```

This is example of the text file :

```
9403133410
A11
R1
5.264214
1905
20220111

9403133410
A11
R1
5.264216
1905
20220112
```

**The input :**
First input: `A11`
Second input: `R1`

**Output**

A11 R1  1905 20220115 5.264222

My goal is to somehow store the previous line of the `A11` the line `9403133410`
And also store the `5.264216` `1905` `20220112` so the 3 lines after the `R1`.

**This is my code :**

```
int o_function() {
    // create mer_modul_input that will take 3 characters
    char mer_modul_input[4];
    char typ_meranej_veliciny[3];
    printf("Zadaj merany modul: \n");
    scanf("%s", mer_modul_input);
    printf("Zadaj typ meranej veliciny: \n");
    scanf("%s", typ_meranej_veliciny);
    printf("%s %s \n", mer_modul_input, typ_meranej_veliciny);

    FILE *file = fopen("dataloger.txt", "r");

    char c;
    while ((c = fgetc(file)) != EOF) {
        printf("%c", c);
    }
    
    fclose(file);
    return 0;
}
```

If you have any ideas how to do it I really appreciate every answer Thank you have a nice day :))

This is the link to the whole project if you want to help me :
https://plum-aleda-91.tiiny.site/

Comment: C, C# and C++ are three ***very*** different programming languages. Please don't spam with language-tags just because the names seems similar.

Comment: That's unsafe code: please restrict the input length with `scanf("%3s", mer_modul_input);` and with `scanf("%2s", typ_meranej_veliciny);`

Comment: Also please take some time to refresh [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). And don't forget how to [edit] your questions to improve them, like actually *ask* a question and describe (in as much details as possible) what problems you have.

Comment: Define a `struct` with for those 6 members. Read in / parse a whole `struct` and *then* if it matches what you are searching, take the action needed.

Comment: "I need to store": Store **where**? I propose you break down your problem in smaller functions: One function to search a line, one function to store results (in a file? In a database?…). Also, you're using `strcpy` and `strstr`, why are you not using `strcmp`? That seems to make no sense. Plus,this can't work.Let me give you a file with a line that has more than 99 characters, and your program actually crashes. Matter of fact, one can abuse it then to do pretty arbitrary things to your computer. (You've built a buffer overflow vulnerability by using 100-length buffers, but not checking length)

Comment: Set up an array of 2 lines ( `char line[2][100]` ) then use a line counter and its "modulo 2" as an index for the input line. Easy to compare `line[ !(cnt&1) ]` with `line[ cnt&1 ]` to find the pair of lines that trigger further output...

Comment: So, never use the C library `str…` functions without the `n` version (`strncpy`, `strnstr`, and so on), which limit maximum length. I know this is probably no option for you because you *have* to do this in C for homework, but doing text processing in C is really the last thing a beginner in C needs to do, or, **should** be doing, considering how annoyingly hard it is to get right (the kind of bug I described above is actually still one of the, if not *the* most common source of exploitable ("hackable") bugs in software. {{1/2}}

Comment: C is really not the language of choice if you need somewhat usable string handling. It's just been around since 1970, so that's in what all the classic string processing tools were written, nevertheless. You *can* write safe string handling in C, it's just relatively complicated, and if you don't want to write something classic, why would you? Definitely not something I'd teach my students during an introductory course, at all.) {{2/2}}

Comment: btw: Your use of `scanf()` is dangerous, but `fgets()` will not overfill a buffer supplied, and guarantees the buffer will be filled with a null-terminated string (including the '\n' if it fits on this intake.) Just so you know...